# VBA to copy only new data from one workbook to another workbook (date based)

Tags: excel, vba

This is my first time around here and my first steps with VBA (I have done some successful coding already).

This is my issue now: I have a workbook where data is being updated manually daily in 2 worksheets. On another workbook I want to have the same data (it runs some different reports), so I'm trying to pull from the first only the new data added if comparing the dates on both workbooks. Right now I'm doing it with formulas, but I end up with a very big file (>100Mb).

After a long search on the web, trying to use some examples and explantions, this is what I have but I can't manage to run it. Can any of you help me on this? I know that I'm confusing myself with the cells and rows, that's why I need some help :)

```
Sub Copy_Paste_Date_based()

Dim startdateN As Date, enddateN As Date, startdateS As Date, enddateS As Date
Dim rng As Range, rngN As Range, rngS As Range
Dim destRowN As Long, destRowS As Long
Dim wbDest As Workbook
Dim shtSrcN As Worksheet, shtSrcS As Worksheet, shtDestN As Worksheet, shtDestS As Worksheet
Dim c As Range

Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open(Filename:="G:\Construction ENGINEERING\01. Follow Up\05. Monitoring\03. Tunnels\03. Ground water\Piezometric level\OLD\Piezometer_CP_GW_Report_vTEST.xlsm")
Set shtSrcN = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALLData - NORTH")
Set shtSrcS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ALLData - SOUTH")
Set shtDestN = Workbooks("Piezometer_CP_GW_Report_vTEST.xlsm").Worksheets("Piezometer_data NORTH")
Set shtDestS = Workbooks("Piezometer_CP_GW_Report_vTEST.xlsm").Worksheets("Piezometer_data SOUTH")


Set rngN = shtSrcN.Range("A:A")
Set rngS = shtSrcS.Range("A:A")

startdateN = shtDestN.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Value
enddateN = shtSrcN.Range("AQ2").Value
startdateS = shtDestS.Range("A1").End(xlUp).Value
' currently stuck debugging the line below, can't understand what is wrong
enddateS = shtSrcS.Range("AG2").Value


Set rng = Application.Intersect(shtSrcN.Range("A:A"), shtSrcN.UsedRange)

'Find range based on dates for Data in North and past it
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdateN And c.Value <= enddateN Then
        'Starting one cell to the right of c,
        '  copy a 70-cell wide block to the other sheet,
        '  pasting right of the las date value column
        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(0, 70).Copy _
                      shtDestN.startdateN.Offset(0, 1).Select

    End If
Next

'Find range based on dates for Data in South and past it
For Each c In rng.Cells
    If c.Value >= startdateS And c.Value <= enddateS Then
        'Starting one cell to the right of c,
        '  copy a 104-cell wide block to the other sheet,
        '  pasting right of the las date value column
        c.Offset(0, 0).Resize(0, 104).Copy _
                      shtDestS.startdateS.Offset(0, 1).Select

    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: on which step error comes?

Comment: at the moment at the definition of the enddateS (I put a comment mentioning it). The part below haven't been able to test it yet because of this; as I said I took these lines after some research so I don't know if they are good or not

Comment: What error do you get, and what is the value of `shtSrcS.Range("AG2").Value`?

Comment: The error that I get is explained above. The value are the End date, or said in other words the latest date in the updated data base workbook (first), I set up a cell that gets this value in that workbook.

Comment: I see no mention of the error above.

Comment: I get the error on the **enddateS** line. The rest I haven't been able to test it yet because of this; as I said I took these lines after some research so I don't know if they are good or not

Comment: This was already asked, but I dont see an answer. What is the value in this cell? `shtSrcS.Range("AG2").Value`? Put a breakpoint on it and use your debug window to print the value. Is it by chance blank? if it's blank, you cannot put it into a `Date` variable.

Comment: The value is a date. Summarizing: I have a workbook A that is updated with new data manually, and from which I get the "the last date" (**enddate** value) that will be compared with the "the last date" in workbook B (**startdate**) to define which rows have the new data in workbook A. Maybe I'm complicating myself and it is easier to just copy the whole block of data every time ... I'm open to suggestions :)